# Are close vote audits too obvious/confusing?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I see something like this very often:

[image: Example of a problematic audit]

This question is in the review queue, but it shows as already closed. Still, I can leave it open or close it. At first this is confusing, after two or three of those you realize those are just poor audits.

Of course this thing makes sure you're focused (because it's weird), but a proper audit does the same (you're informed that it was a test and you've passed/failed).

Audits like this one are obvious to recognize and can be easily passed just by navigating to the original question and checking if it's already closed. Even a bot can do that, so the audit doesn't serve one of its purposes.

Another thing is the suspicious question score - questions flagged to be closed rarely have a score better than 2 (of course there are exceptions).

Shouldn't audits be crafted more carefully?